# Installing Exchange Server 2013 Filtering Management Service Error 2201

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-service, server-setup, exchange-2013

I'm currently trying to install Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 on a Windows Server 2012 x64 machine.

The setup goes smoothly until the step "Mailbox role: Transport service".
There, the setup hangs at 98% for several (long) minutes and throws this error :

[image]

```
Error:
The following error was generated when "$error.Clear(); 
          if ($RoleStartTransportService)
          {
              start-SetupService -ServiceName MSExchangeTransport -MaxWaitTimeForRunningState 0:0:40
          }
        " was run: "Service 'FMS' failed to reach status 'Running' on this server.".
```

Obviously it has something to do with the FMS service. After a reboot, I tried to start it manually, and got an "Unexpected error".

I then went to see the event log and found this error from `FIPFS` marked as `critical` with ID `2201`:

General info on the error states this :

```
The current permissions for the FIP-FS configuration file "accès au chemin d" may be incorrect; access was denied.
```

Apparently there is a config file somewhere but I cant find it...

The detailed infos are the following :

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
   <System>
      <Provider Name="Microsoft-Filtering-FIPFS" Guid="{1BE3A000-EA09-4AB8-B0A0-30BBB6793D80}" /> 
      <EventID>2201</EventID> 
      <Version>0</Version> 
      <Level>1</Level> 
      <Task>0</Task> 
      <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
      <Keywords>0x8000000000000000</Keywords> 
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-04-13T02:30:30.371225000Z" /> 
      <EventRecordID>35120</EventRecordID> 
      <Correlation /> 
      <Execution ProcessID="5816" ThreadID="9076" /> 
      <Channel>Application</Channel> 
      <Computer>ks204653.TheGroup.local</Computer> 
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-18" /> 
  </System>
  <EventData>
      <Data Name="FilePath">accès au chemin d</Data> 
      <!-- Note from myself: this means "access to path D" -->
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

From this log I understand that FIPFS is trying to access D:\ and cant. The D drive is my virtual DVD drive where the Exchange Server image is loaded (Please note that it's a legal image taken with my MSDNAA account). I installed with all settings left to default, logged on Administrator account. I also tried to `Run as Administrator` Setup.EXE with no success.

This is my first time installing Exchange Server, and I have to admit I'm having a hard time and Google did not help with this error.

Any idea about what I could do ?

If you need additional infos please ask in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Prior to disabling IPV6, perhaps you can try changing the order of bindings? Making IPV4 first. As well, please validate that the server is properly resolving it's own name through IPV4.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I had the same issue..
To resolve it I had to disabled the tcpip ip6 on the local Area connecton
i.e

1. Open Registry Editor.
2. Locate the following registry subkey:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINESYSTEMCurrentControlSetServicesTcpip6Parameters
3. In the details pane, click New, and then click DWORD (32-bit) Value.
4. Type DisabledComponents, and then press ENTER.
5. Double-click DisabledComponents, and then type 0xffffffff in Hexadecimal

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Event Viewer and check the Application Logs
   if you have this error :

> "The FIP-FS configuration file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FIP-FS\Data\ConfigurationServer.xml" is missing."

If so then:

2. from your Exchange 2013 source find the `ConfigurationServer.xml` file (it should be somewhere like this : "\Setup\Filtering\" (if you do not have the source DVD just download my file from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8ju0_68wXJUYXR3T08xTnB6VWM/view?usp=sharing))
3. copy `ConfigurationServer.xml` to `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FIP-FS\Data"`
4. Start Microsoft filtering management service
5. Start  Microsoft Exchange Transport service
6. check all of Microsoft Exchange Services are running...